# "Set" COM object properties in batch in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I have to set the properties of a COM object.

The COM object has a `Set` function that takes a key (string) and a value (variant) as parameters. For example I can do : `com_object->Set("name", "John")`.

I have many properties to set, but I don't know how to do it in C++. In VB.Net it would look like that:
`com_object.Set "name,age", Array("M2", 1)`

I would like to do the same in C++ but I don't know the syntax.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I have written to access properties in batch:

```
  template < class ComObjectType >
  void read(ComObjectType com_object, std::string const& fields)
  {
    COleSafeArray data_array_;
    data_array_ = com_object->GetGet((LPCSTR)fields.c_str());
    long index = 0;
    VARIANT value_temp_;
    _variant_t value_reader_;
    data_array_.GetElement(&index, &value_temp_);
    value_reader_.Attach(value_temp_);
    std::string str1 = (LPCSTR)((_bstr_t) value_reader_)
    ++index
    data_array_.GetElement(&index, &value_temp_);
    value_reader_.Attach(value_temp_);
    long long1 = value_reader_.lVal;

  }
```

Then I call this function (which actually does not do much but is just there for the demonstration. The IAPIOrderObj* can be anything but it is defined in the .tlh file of the API I am being provided with, and it inherits from IDispatch interface.

```
MYAPI::IAPIOrderObj* my_obj;
read< IAPIOrderObj* >(my_obj, "StatusString,StatusCode");
```

Comment: Do you work with VS2010? How does definition of `com_object` look?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to access the COM component MFC or ATL or only c++ library like _bsrt_t I cannot derive this information from your code snippet.

With some basic assumptions here are some points to consider.

1. Normally VB uses the IDispatch interface to access the COM components. From C++ there may be a native interface which may be much more easier to access than the IDispatch interface. From the com_object you can query this c++ interface.
2. Always use the COM strings (BSTR, SysAllocString allocated) for passing string information across.
3. Don't typecast from LPCSTR to _bstr_t. Both string representation has different meanings. Always use proper conversion functions to do the conversions.

Hope this helps.